# How to use Whatsapp mobile application on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

In my Android I have "Whatsapp" application running. But mobile freak I am not, and specially the mobile keyboards.

So how can I run my same application, same account from my Ubuntu desktop PC?

**Follow up:**

Just to do keyboard routing, i have used [WiFiKeyboard apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en). Which allows me to takeover the Android input fields access via web link to type in my PC keyboard, and then it re-route the keys to Mobile.

Features:

- Allows me to copy and paste large texts to Android input fields without using the keyboard of Android but simply using my Desktop PC, via web link `http://android.ip.address.goes.here:port/`
- Allows me to have key submit which is similar to key press of mobile set itself

At-least works without having mobile in rooted. Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to install the Android Emulator to run that. Follow the tutorial listed here:

[How to install WhatsApp on Linux Ubuntu PC with Android emulator (Updated 23/12/12) HD - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WC__Co3hyYI).

Comment: Whatsapp service requires you to verify the mobile phone number via text messaging (SMS). This is not possible in an emulator without a SIM card and mobile network radio.

Comment: I have Whatsapp running on my Android Gingerbread emulator of my Android SDK on Ubuntu 12.04. Mobile Verification done long back, texting sharing media all going full swing!

Comment: How about instead you make a script of the movie for us?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 5):

I have found two solutions for this. In both cases you need to somehow run the mobile version, so that you get an account first.

1. There is already an experimental client of Whatsapp for  Ubuntu 12.10 . 
   You have to open a terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:m-gehre/ppa
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install whosthere
   ```

   You will have to confirm for every step. The information comes from [here](https://github.com/mgehre/whosthere)
   Unfortunately dependencies for Ubuntu 12.04 are not covered
2. Whatsapp seems to be using customized XMPP. A [German blog](http://www.revengeday.de/2012/09/whatsapp-via-xmpp-protokoll-benutzen/) claims to have managed to make it work by Adium messenger and that it should also work with Pidgin the same way. I will try to test it and post here a translation. **Update** this does not work any more

Comment: Great. Looking forward one working solution. Cause 24/7 we use Ubuntu only for WhatsAPP have to go in mobile explicitly its disturbing, and would be great if that can be done from Ubuntu desktop native way.

Answer (score 1):

after reading [this article](http://blog.maarten.abbink.me/2012/02/why-whatsapp-messenger-wont-work-on.html) the conclusion is this: whattsup can not work under XMPP clients, or it could, but you have to do rocketscience hacking.

Also, from **wikipedia**:

WhatsApp uses a customized version of the open standard Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP). Upon installation, it creates a user account using one's phone number as username (Jabber ID: [phone number]@s.whatsapp.net). WhatsApp software automatically compares all phone numbers from the device's address book with its central database of WhatsApp users to automatically add contacts to the users WhatsApp contact list. **Previously the Android and s40 versions used an MD5-hashed, reversed-version of the phone's IMEI as password, while the iOS version used the phone's WiFi MAC address instead of IMEI.** **A recent update now generates a random password on the server side.**

Answer (score 0):

it can be done ive got whatssapp working on ubuntu 13.10 with noproblems
virtual box 4.22 required and gemymotion emulator
when you are asked for the sms code just type any number i will then give you the option to be called to your phone pick up the call type in the numbers you are told over the phone on your emulator and thats it

do not use your whatsapp in your phone while your emulator is running or you will need  to re do the verification procces in your phone

they only allow  whatsapp to run in one device only