# How to install Telegram Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: install-from-source, telegram

I want to install [Telegram Desktop software](https://desktop.telegram.org/) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have downloaded the tsetup.0.6.15.tar.xz file. Now I want to know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 49):

## How to install Telegram Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04

[Download the Telegram Desktop client](https://desktop.telegram.org/) and extract `tsetup.0.6.15.tar.xz`. You can easily do this in the file manager (nautilus). Just right-click the file and click `extract here`. Now you have a folder called `Telegram`.

Move this folder to `/opt`. You can do this using the file manager, but you'll need to start it with root privileges. You can do this by typing the following in a terminal: (you can find the "opt" folder in "computer")

```
sudo nautilus
```

After the move, double-click the telegram binary `/opt/Telegram/Telegram`. The last thing we need to do is add Telegram to the "applications" menu. This happens automatically if you right-click the icon of the running app and choose "lock to launcher".

## Other options for using telegram in Linux

Telegram is also available as:

- Google Chrome app
- web-app
- scope, *and other platforms*.

You can find different alternatives here: https://askubuntu.com/a/456121/172367

Comment: I don't have the option to click 'lock to launcher'. Is there something else I can do to add Telegram to the application menu?

Comment: Strange thing: if I run Telegram under the /Downloads directory, everything is fine and the launcher has the Telegram icon. BUT if I move Telegram folder to any other directory I tried (including e.g. my user's home or Desktop), I don't get an icon, only a default gray "?" icon. I tried moving it to /opt and lock it to launcher but it doesn't start, although it is ok if I have it in Downloads directory. Why is that?

Comment: I found a solution: intially I ran it from the /Downloads directory. At the first start, a /.TelegramDesktop directory is created, storing the settings and the data. If I delete this directory and move it somewhere else, it works as expected!

Comment: Telegram creates `~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop` file describing launcher entry on the first start. If you move application's directory after that you should simply fix a path in `Exec` line of this file.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sudo nautilus` instead use `gksudo nautilus`

Answer (score 47):

In your terminal type this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```

Comment: Exactly. downloading and extracting files is not the way to go. For most (relatively) mainstream sofware packages, add the ppa to be sure about compatibility.

Comment: The PPA seems abandoned. As for now a week has already passed since Telegram 0.9.10 release and the PPA is still at 0.9.6 (4 releases old).

Comment: @Ivan At time of writing the PPA is up to date with the stable release. It had one problem though, running through Ubuntu Dash menu didn't seem to work. I created a desktop launcher with the run command: /opt/telegram/Telegram.

Comment: after using this one I am also experiencing problems with opening tg: links

Comment: Note that for some reason one needs `/opt/telegram/Telegram -- %u` command to run telegram. `telegram` is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Extract it from folder tsetup.0.8.36.tar.xz and put this folder wherever you want...and run the file named telegram in executable mode by double clicking it..that did for me

Comment: whats the error one getting during this process?