# I had trouble while trying install Telegram on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, telegram

I had followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Pu-miD1f-s) video tutorial but I couldn't install Telegram, because of this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package telegramm
E: Unable to locate package desktop
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out a common mistake that newbies make. I'm pretty sure you typed the command wrong. It's `sudo apt-get install telegram-desktop`, not `sudo apt-get install telegramm desktop`. Hence, instead of trying to find the package `telegram-desktop`, it looked for the packages `telegramm` and `desktop` - since those packages don't exist, you get two errors in return.

Now, everything else on the video seems to be fine. If you followed the steps correctly up to this point, you should already have the NoobsLab "repository" (package source) and the only missing step is to type the installation command properly (that `apt-get`) and let the computer do its work. It's that simple.

*P.S.: Please, next time give more information about your problem. For example, the step of the tutorial where everything gets wrong. It's only because it's an obvious problem to me that I could reply to you - otherwise, we'd have to do more research than necessary. This is a community where people aren't getting paid for helping, this is done in our spare time. Thank you for understanding.*

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to download telegram from the source.
This question is answered in detail here:
[How to install Telegram Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556532/how-to-install-telegram-desktop-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)