# Unity Dash and Telegram

Tags: unity-dash, telegram

I installed Telegram following these instruction:

```
Run the following lines:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
To run, simply open Dash and type Telegram. You will see an option called "Telegram Desktop". If you encounter any issue like Telegram not opening the Desktop version, but instead the Web version, run the following:

/opt/telegram/Telegram
This should make the Telegram Desktop version appear on the Ubuntu Dash.
```

As i found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/456121/396145).

But Telegram still doesn't appear on the Ubuntu Dash.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I also installed Telegram but using the tar file from the Telegram website.

I had to search for the Telegram app once I moved it to the /opt folder and then dragged and dropped it onto the Unity sidebar launcher

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue, You must create "telegram.desktop" file in :

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

Then paste the following contents to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Telegram
Exec=/opt/telegram/Telegram
Comment=Network taking back our right to privacy.
Icon=/opt/telegram/telegram.svg
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;
```

After save the file, Telegram will appear!

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @Nurlan what is output of this command: 'ls /opt/telegram/Telegram'

Comment: the output is /opt/telegram/Telegram.  Finally I managed to run telegram from dash. But, didn't really understand what was a problem)