# How do I start Telegram from the command line?

Tags: command-line, execute-command, telegram

How do I start Telegram messenger from the command line?

I have tried "telegram", but it's not that.

I have installed Telegram via ppa: [ppa:atareao/telegram](https://askubuntu.com/a/456121/181242).

Comment: How did you install it? The Telegram app comes packaged in a standalone .zip file (or .tar file, can't quite remember). Where did you extract this?

Comment: I have installed it via [ppa:atareao/telegram](http://askubuntu.com/a/456121/181242). I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you see it in /opt? Try running `/opt/telegram/Telegram` at the command-line

Comment: @Seth Yes, it's there. "/opt/telegram/Telegram". Would be more convenient if it started like other programs, like `firefox`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you installed telegram from the PPA, it is likely installed in `/opt`. Probably under `/opt/telegram`.  You should be able to launch it from the command-line by running:

```
/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

but if you wanted to make this easier you can create a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin` like so:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/telegram/Telegram /usr/local/bin/telegram
```

you can then launch telegram with the command:

```
telegram
```

Comment: ok, I guess it's the packager's fault (?) that they didn't create a symbolic link when installing. Thanks!

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov yes it would be their oversight.

Comment: No, it is not an oversight. It is packaged to be installed in /opt/telegram, rather than in /usr.

Comment: @dobey if you're going to install everyday software it doesn't make sense to not put it in PATH somehow. A symlink to /usr/*local*/bin (not the same thing as a normal app installed in /usr) is a good way to do that. Much better than adding a folder from /opt directly to PATH.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 17.10, 18.04 and above, If you have installed using Ubuntu Software Manager, you can launch it using the following command in terminal:

```
telegram-desktop
```

if you want to start it minimized in tray use the following command (e.g you want to create an start up entry):

```
telegram-desktop -startintray
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where you installed your **Telegram**,
you can easily launch the script, see the example below (I installed it in directory named `soft`).

```
(base) user@user:~/soft/Telegram$ ls
Telegram  Updater
(base) user@user:~/soft/Telegram$ ./Telegram
```

Voila, you have it running.