# is there any way so i can use whats app on ubuntu ,i dont have android have android smart phone,

Tags: wine, android

i tried genymotion and virtual box combination it worked for very small time.then i tried android X86 operating system but on this os whats app is not available ,i used "shashlik" but just getting black screen ,also used koplayer in wine but  showing errors .anybody please help me install in whats app.
[image]

Comment: Try this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/06/whatsapp-client-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install WhatsApp?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333850/how-to-install-whatsapp) and possible duplicate of [Install whatsapp webapp on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/684415/install-whatsapp-webapp-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Whatsie. You can download a .deb package from [here](https://github.com/Aluxian/Whatsie/releases) for your architecture, and simply double click to install it

Comment: I think he means to actually run whatsapp on linux and not to use a whatsapp web client. Although I could be wrong, it's a bit hard to tell

Comment: @arno you are right ,whatsie needs smartphone which i dont have.