# WhatsApp app for Ubuntu (non-web)

Tags: 18.04, whatsapp

Are there are any non-web based apps for WhatsApp (think Skype) for Ubuntu?

I've read a bunch of things touching on this but all have ended up saying it was just a Trojan horse and pointed to the web app.

All the apps I found were a few years old, so I'm just checking whether there are any current ones.

Comment: I specifically put, not a webapp... that other question asks for a webapp.

Comment: This question needs to be directed to the Whatsapp developers. There is only a Whatsapp webclient.

Comment: I'm sorry about that - I had marked the question closed as duplicate, re-read, and removed my vote, but forgot to remove the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anbox snap installation fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-snap-installation-fails)

Comment: Is this a solution for you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/684415/install-whatsapp-webapp-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an unofficial WhatsApp client for Linux in the Ubuntu Software app: `whatsdesk`.

[image: unofficial WhatsApp client for Linux]

> WhatsDesk is a unofficial client of whatsapp
>
> this project only insert a web whatsapp in a electron app and add desktop notification

It is available as snap package from the store (see above) and [.deb package for download](https://zerkc.gitlab.io/whatsdesk/).

Sources and more information can be found on https://gitlab.com/zerkc/whatsdesk.

Comment: afaik, this still requires you to use whatsapp web, no? I think whatsdeck just syncs to your phone over wifi and can't run WhatsApp without it being installed on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own whatsapp app:

- Type terminal `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/whatsapp-webapp.desktop`
- Copy following text to opened screen

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WhatsApp
GenericName=WhatsApp
Comment=WhatsApp desktop webapp
#Exec=webapp-container --store-session-cookies --webappUrlPatterns=https?://*.whatsapp.com/* --user-agent-string='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' https://web.whatsapp.com %u
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
# If you want icon, type path of icon
# Icon=
Categories=Network;Application;
Keywords=WhatsApp;webapp;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=WhatsApp
StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
```

- Finally, keyboard shortcuts to open | create

```sh
bash -c "wmctrl -xa web.whatsapp.com || /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/"
```

Comment: lol wut. This is literally just thinly veiled WhatsApp Web.