# How make to minimize app to tray on close

Tags: startup, webapps, minimize, whatsapp

I use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144265/859739) page to create a WhatsApp application, but I want when I close or minimize app it's going to tray and not close complete.

And how to add startup to minimize.

I test alltray, but not work in 19.04

Answer (score 1):

Using WhatsDesk downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre select `Show/Hide WhatsDesk` and then go to Tools and select `Close Window and Exit` and/or `Skip Taskbar` as required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's unofficial app