# How to get whatsapp as a desktop app on Ubuntu?

Tags: whatsapp

Hi this is my second day using linux so I am a noob. But when looking for a solution for my question I found this question: [Install WhatsApp webapp on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684415/install-whatsapp-webapp-on-ubuntu) the top ranked answer does nothing for me, I just end up with the text copied in a window.

I assume there are some obvious steps which I am missing as someone completely new to linux. I tried saving that file and finding it through terminal but the directory where it's supposedly saved doesn't exist.

Comment: There are *four* answers in the question that you linked to. Are you really saying that you tried the first half of just one and then gave up? Or are you asking for tutorials on how Ubuntu software and the terminal work? Your question seems unclear to me. There is no official WhatsApp release for Linux, so all answers will be a bit kludgy to some degree.

Comment: @user535733 The one I assume he's referring to is the one that opens the web browser in [application mode](https://technastic.com/open-websites-in-application-mode-google-chrome/).

Comment: are you use Kubuntu?

Comment: I am asking about the top voted answer, because I want to learn to implement what 59 people thought was a good answer. I wish I could ask about it in a comment under that answer but I couldn't write a comment there for a lack of points.

Comment: no I am not using Kubuntu

Comment: I recommend trying franz which is a great tool that combines many messaging services (including whatsapp) into one interface: https://meetfranz.com/. Not posting as an answer since it isn't a way of installing whatsapp, per se, but a way of using whatsapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file in `~/.local/share/applications`, so you don't have to mess with `sudo`:

1. Open gedit, paste the text shown in the answer you link, and save as `<the name you prefer>.desktop`, let's say `whataspp.desktop`, under the directory mentioned.
2. In the `Exec` line, you are telling which web browser to use, using the absolute path to the executable.

As said in the other answer, if you are going to use chrome, or chromium, you have to install it and change the line with the path to the executable. Use `which google-chrome` (or `which chromium-browser`) to check the path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I now run the file from activities, it just opens my opera browser which I use as my main browser. Am I still doing something wrong? I prefer not to use google chrome as suggested by other answers

Comment: @Olivier sorry, I was sure `/usr/bin/gnome-www-browser` was gnome's browser. I was wrong, it just opens the default, in your case opera. I'll edit the answer accordingly. It would seem that this is a feature of chrome/chromium, I couldn't find the same in firefox or opera yet. The alternative to chrome would be chromium then.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple.
Open the terminal by pressing **Ctrl** + **alt** + **t** and just type the following command:

```
sudo snap install whatsapp-for-linux
```

and then press y when an option is prompted. It will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For a new user, the easiest solution is to try a an unofficial Snap package.

1. Open your Ubuntu Software application.
2. Search for WhatsApp.

... or ...

https://snapcraft.io/search?q=whatsapp . Pick one and click "install"

Both options will show the same Snap packages.

Comment: can you trust any program that shows up there?

Comment: That's a completely different question. And it has been asked before. Use the Search box at the top of every AskUbuntu page to start your research on that. ALL whatsapp-on-Linux solutions are unofficial, so you must do your own research on whom to trust.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have Google Chrome, if not, then [install it](https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/).
2. Open terminal
3. Run `gedit /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/whatsapp.desktop`
4. Once the text editor opens paste this code in it. Save it and exit.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=WhatsApp
    GenericName=WhatsApp
    Comment=WhatsApp desktop webapp
    Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    StartupNotify=true
    MimeType=text/plain;
    Categories=Network;Application;
    Keywords=WhatsApp;webapp;
    X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=WhatsApp
    StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
```

5. Now you can find whatsapp through the Activities menu, if not then run

```
    nautilus /home/$USER/.local/share/applications
```

6. Right click whatsapp.desktop,in properties ensure "Allow to run as program" is checked. Then open it, select "Trust and Launch".

Any errors please let me know.

Comment: Don't run `sudo gedit...`, you don't need sudo to create files in your home folder, and also it's a bad idea.

Comment: Can we do something similar in Firefox as well?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity i have now corrected

Comment: Can I apply this for github?

Comment: @preIdiot sure !!!

Comment: One more...how to launch these from terminal eg.,writing  Whatsapp  in terminal

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/385169/1013762

Comment: perfect! works!

Answer (score -1):

You'll first have to install Chrome to do this, because Firefox doesn't natively support installing websites as applications yet. To install Chrome, open a Terminal window and type:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Type in the admin password if asked. Now, open [WhatsApp Web](http://web.whatsapp.com) in Chrome, and sign in. After signing in, click on the options button in the top right corner, click on **"More tools"**, then click on **"Create shortcut..."**, and click on the checkmark that says: **"Open as window"**, then click on **"Create"**

Now, open the apps screen or the Activities overview, and type "Whatsapp" in the search bar, then right click on the WA icon, and click on "Add to favourites". Done!

Comment: Did you ever try to run `sudo apt install chrome`?

Comment: @Pilot6 well I forgot the command (I'm sorry for that). I've fixed the installation instructions now