# Whatsapp on Linux

Tags: whatsapp

I was looking for WhatsApp for my Ubuntu but I found out there is no available on Linux.
I saw an unofficial alternative called WhatsDesk and I would like to ask if the application is safe in terms of privacy and usability.
I know there is Whatsapp web, but I would prefer to keep this option as the last.
Thank you for the answer and have a great day!

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Franz](https://meetfranz.com/). It's a great little program that can support multiple chat apps, including WhatsApp, all in one place. There's no support for calls yet, but if you're primarily interested in messaging, it works great.

Answer (score 1):

In as much as any such package is safe in terms of privacy on the internet, yes.

I believe it uses the same end to end encrypted  security as WhatsApp does.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know your safe options are:

- [Install whatsapp-for-linux](https://snapcraft.io/install/whatsapp-for-linux/ubuntu) (most popular unofficial app)
- Use WhatsApp web
- [Create your own whatsapp app](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144265)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure about the app and use Gnome and have Chrome installed, you can try placing this in your /usr/share/applications folder [whatsapp-webapp.desktop](https://github.com/fredtux/ubuntu-optimizations/blob/main/gnome-apps/whatsapp-webapp.desktop)

LE: There is no "app", just Chrome running with the --app argument as stated by the Exec directive

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

Yes, this is from my own repo made specifically for my own use but I decided to share it a few days ago.