# BlueStacks for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, android

I'm looking for BlueStacks or something like it for Ubuntu 12.04,if I can install BlueStacks, how do I do it? If not, is there another software that can run Android apps? I just want to play Geometry Dash Lite,so if there is another way,it's fine too. I saw videos that teach how to install it but the links don't work for me.
Thanks to whoever helps :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install WhatsApp?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333850/how-to-install-whatsapp)

Comment: Or possible duplicate of [can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1732/can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You may try Archon http://archon-runtime.github.io/, which runs the packaged apk as google chrome browser extension. You will need the Archon packager from google play in order to package the apk from phone to your linux desktop.

You better try the 2.1 version of Archon as it contains better support for various apks.

How to in detail:

1. When you have 32bit Ubuntu, choose Chrome 32-bit / Chrome OS 32-bit. When you have 64bit Ubuntu, choose Intel x86 Chrome 64-bit / Chrome OS 64-bit. Download the zip.
2. Install google chrome on Ubuntu and unzip the downloaded zip to a directory.
3. Launch google chrome and enable in the extensions developer mode. Then load as unpacked extension the directory where you unzipped downloaded archon.
   [image]
4. Next download on your phone or tabled archon packager from the playstore. Run Archon Packager on your phone, choose installed application, choose Geometry Dash Lite and export to zip on your phone.
5. Transfer the zip archive from your phone to your computer. Unzip the archive to a folder (Geometry Dash Lite), then go to Google chrome and load unpacked extension this time the Geometry Dash Lite.
6. In Google Chrome you have now two unpacked extensions: Archon and Geometry Dash Lite.
7. To launch the game simple click on run in google chrome extensions or search the application name in the Ubuntu Dash.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I went to the link you gave me, 2.1, there are 3 options...Intel x86 Chrome 64-bit / Chrome OS 64-bit;Chrome 32-bit / Chrome OS 32-bit; or ARM (i.e ARM-based Chromebooks)? Sorry that I'm horrible with computers...

Comment: See edit of my answer.

Comment: How do I unzip a zip? Just pretend that I'm a first grade kid that knows nothing about computers...

Comment: Double click it in nautilus / files. It opens the file with archiver, which is ubuntu's archive manager. Use drag and drop or simply click on extract and choose the destination directory. Drag and drop is easy- you click the folder in archiver hold down the left mouse button and pull it to the files window/ nautilus, then release left mouse button. The archiver then extracts the files/folders.

Comment: Where's my desnation?

Comment: You can create a folder in your home directory. That will be your destination. To create a folder open nautilus, choose home directory, right click in nautilus - create folder. Give it a name and you're good to go.

Comment: What's nautilus? Do I just create a folder in the Home folder?

Comment: Nautilus is just a name for the Ubuntu file manager. Yes, you just create a folder in your Home Folder. Nautilus and your files icon under the dash is the same thing. Sorry that I confused you.

Comment: So all I do is just... create a folder in the home folder and name it however i would like and then...? sorry i just know nothing about computers...

Comment: You create a folder then unzip downloaded archon zip to this folder. Then create a second folder for the packaged android program. Unzip the zip transfered from your phone that you created on the phone using Archon packager (download from play store). After having both directories filled with data, you launch google chrome, enable developer mode as in the picture and load unpacked extension the archon home folder and the android program home folder. After this you can find your android program in the dash.

Comment: So sorry, I had been really busy with school lately, the tests are coming up... Umm, so, I had been looking through all the comments, you said to drag and drop OR extract and choose the destination, but when I extract, it just comes out a folder beside it... :/ So can I just drag and drop the... Sorry, :confused:, the extracted folder which is called "vladikoff-archon-e3c9b322402a",or do I drag and drop the "vladikoff-archon-e3c9b322402a.zip"? Ohhhhhh, or do I drag and drop the thingy inside the zip thingy??? Like,when it opens with the Archive Manager,I drag and drop the only thing inside it?

Comment: You drag and drop what is inside the archiver window.

Comment: I'm so sorry, so I just drag and drop everything when i open the zip with archive manager into the fold that i made in the home folder... right?

Comment: Ohhhh, I think I get it, when I drag and dropped the zip into the folder in the home folder, it appeared extracted.

Comment: And then I went to Chrome settings and went to Extensions and checked developer mode, and then clicked on Load unpacked extensions. Now what? Or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: When you click on the Load Unpacked extensions, you select the archon directory - where you unpacked the zip. Then you load a second extension - the packaged android program - this will be a directory again.

Comment: So like, the folder that I unzipped? I load that twice?

Comment: Yes, you do not load it twice. First time you load the archon and second time the application created on your mobile phone with archon packager from play store.

Comment: I loaded it once on my computer, and I downloaded something called ARChon Packager. Now what do I do....? How do I upload the thing on my phone? I do it on my phone? Or do I do it on my computer? Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: You install the desired application you want to transfer on your phone. You install the archon packager application on your phone. Next you run the archon packager on your phone and choose to export the installed application. The archon packager will create a zip file which you transfer from your phone to your computer. You have to unpack the zip and load it as an unpacked extension too. Then you can run it from dash.

Comment: I entered ARChon Packager, I chose "Installed application", then "next", then "WhatsApp"(Just trying, I can use it on web I know), then "next", then"Finish", then the app disappered... :/ I don't get it, what did I do wrong? How do I connect it to my computer?

Comment: The archon packager produces a zip file. Try to look in /sdcard/Chromeapks directory of your phone with file manager. There should be a file Whatsapp.zip. Transfer this file to your computer and unzip it, then load as unpacked extension.

Comment: I don't find Chromeapks... Sorry...

Comment: Install the Archon packager from Google play store. Open the app, select next, then installed application, tap on next, select the application. On the next page you select the Phone or Tablet mode and Portrait or landscape, you can enable the on application to access the hard drive, if it is an application that needs access. You will not need to enable ADB, leave it unchecked. Then Tap on next. On the next page you will get a conversion summary. If it is successful, you can tap on Share Chrome Application and send it for instance through your Gmail account. On the PC you can download the zip.

Comment: Thamks a lot for helping me, something happened to my computer, so I will need your help later. Sorry