# Running Android app on ubuntu directly like wineHQ

Tags: android-emulator

The question is clear from title. Can I run Android app on Ubuntu directly like  (wine).

If Ubuntu and Android both have Linux kernel then why can't we run Android app directly or with help of any other little software?

Comment: Your ubuntu version?

Comment: I am using 16.04 LTS

Comment: Here's a good explanation:  https://www.howtogeek.com/189036/android-is-based-on-linux-but-what-does-that-mean/

Comment: Here's a way to run android apps on ubuntu https://anbox.io/

Comment: I have installed Anbox but it doesn't open when I click the all icon in app drawer. It just flash once and then disappears. So I uninstalled the Anbox.

Comment: Here are some emulators that you can try:  http://techapple.net/2014/05/5-best-android-emulators-linux-run-android-apps-linux-ubuntulinuxmintfedoraarchlinuxopensusemageiacentos-etc/

Answer (score 1):

You can use anbox,it has lot of bugs, but it add some changes in kernel(**this is what you require**).i.e diretly run android app.
I myself use it and works fine,but i had to configure anbox in starting

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Archon runtime extension for google chrome browser. In order to run the app, you will need to package it using archon packager - look for it in the google play store, then load the app as unpacked extension. I explained the details here: [BlueStacks for Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685656/bluestacks-for-ubuntu-12-04/)