# How to install official whatsapp for windows (whatsapp.exe) in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, wine, windows-10, whatsapp

So I recently noticed that whatsapp has published an official app for Microsoft Windows (PC version). I tried to install the same in my Ubuntu using Wine but it fails to install. 
I am being prompted to install .net 4.5. 
Later I see a dialog which says installation failed.
Can somebody guide me how to install the official Whatsapp for windows in my linux. 
P.s - Please don't recommend third part applications for whatsapp.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install WhatsApp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333850/how-to-install-whatsapp)

Comment: "Can somebody help me with this". I doubt we on AU will be able to help. 1. using wine is fishy as is. 2. using bleeding edge windows software aint going to work with wine; wine will take time to catch up with newer windows software. 3, the best experience with windows software is using windows: install vbox/vmware, install windows in it, install whatsapp in it. Create backups from the container to overcome possible virusses.

Comment: @George , This is not a duplicate since I am asking how to install the official whatsapp application in ubuntu via wine and not a third party whatsapp application developed by XYZ. I don't think its same as the link you have added. Please read the description of the post.

Comment: @Rinzwind , Installing virtualbox/vmware defeats the whole purpose of using linux. Why will I Install another windows in vbox just to install one application. I just want to somehow use the official whatsapp application for windows in my linux

Comment: No it doesn't. It really does not. The need for you to use software restricted to Windows is. And there is nothing wrong to use the OS software is intended for. Just use it legally and careful to avoid the issues windows plague. "I just want to somehow use the official whatsapp application for windows in my linux" Tell microsoft to make a version for linux.

Comment: @Rinzwind I think Whatsapp is owned by Facebook, not Windows

Comment: And Microsoft owns 3% of facebook. Seems small but the leverage that gives is amazing. The BEST experience using Linux you get is using vbox/vmware and use windows in it and whatsapp in that.

Comment: Why not just use Whatsapp Web? What does the app do that the web version doesn't?

Comment: @edwinksl , Well, Whatsapp web needs Google chrome/Browser to be running which need a good chunk of RAM and I cannot get message notifications when I close the browser.

Comment: @PrashantKumar no reason to be argumentative... you have your answers... either run Virtualbox (as per @Rinzwind) or Whatsapp Web (as per @edwinksl).

Comment: @heynnema I actually didn't got the answers I was seeking. If I had to use virtualbox or whatsapp web, I would not have asked this question in the first place.

Comment: @PrashantKumar https://www.winehq.org/ doesn't show that anybody has been able to get Whatsapp running with Wine. Not too much runs with Wine, actually.